# Django: app displays 400 error when deployed on server

Tags: python, django, nginx, supervisord

Actually I have two problem here.I have one vps(bare minimum for testing) on which I have 2-3 apps.I have just deployed another app on it & got a free domain name from freenom.com.I use `supervisor+nginx` for hosting the app.For no reason I am getting this `Bad Request (400)` when I visit the domain.Generally this occurs when you don't put the the domain name in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list but I have set this up.
The second problem is that I have `DEBUG = True` still it's just displaying the bare minimum error response instead of full stack trace hence I am not sure what errors I am actually getting & unable to debug it.

1. No error logs in the `gunicorn-error.log` file.
2. No error logs in the `nginx-error.log` file.
3. No error logs in the `nginx-access.log` file.

**My `gunicorn_start` config**

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="hrms_app"
DIR=/home/kunsab/projects/hrms_venv/hrms
USER=kunsab
GROUP=kunsab
WORKERS=3
BIND=127.0.0.1:8081
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=hrms.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=hrms.wsgi
LOG_LEVEL=error

cd $DIR
source ../bin/activate

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DIR:$PYTHONPATH

exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=$BIND \
  --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
  --log-file=-
```

**supervisor config:**

```
[program:hrms_app]
command=/home/kunsab/projects/hrms_venv/bin/gunicorn_start
user=kunsab
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/kunsab/projects/hrms_venv/logs/gunicorn-error.log
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for hrms project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '9#h(zvlwo4gmci-jr-3t_5s1y_vu7_07rox6*(y=kcirm!w+cl'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['gthrms.tk','galentichrms.tk','127.0.0.1']

BASE_URL = 'http://galentichrms.tk/'

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
]


# Application definition
DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MY_APPS = [
    'employees',
    'clients',
    'projects',
    'payroll',
    'locations',
    'marketing',
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'debug_toolbar',
    'mathfilters'
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + MY_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', # disable to view the pdf files in the model iframe
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hrms.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'hrms.context.global_constants'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hrms.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'hrms',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '*****'
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators


password_validators = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [] if DEBUG else password_validators

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ("%d/%m/%Y",)

USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True



# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR.joinpath('static')
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR.joinpath('assets')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR.joinpath('media')

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mailtrap.io'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '******'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*****'
EMAIL_PORT = '2525'

DEFAULT_EMAIL_RECEIPENTS = [
    'test@test.com'
]

# CELERY CONFIG
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
# CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
# CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
# CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

**nginx config:**

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;

    # add here the ip address of your server
    # or a domain pointing to that ip (like example.com or www.example.com)
    server_name galentichrms.tk;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/kunsab/projects/hrms_venv/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/kunsab/projects/hrms_venv/logs/nginx-error.log;

    
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/kunsab/projects/hrms_venv/hrms/assets/;
    }
    # media files
    location /media/ {
        alias /home/kunsab/projects/hrms_venv/hrms/media/;
    }

    
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        #proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Seems like the nginx is terminating the requests and not forwarding to django. Post your nxing config file.

Comment: @xyres I have posted the nginx config.please take a look.

Comment: `listen [::]:80;`--  this means nginx will only serve IPv6 requests. But seeing browser logs, the requests are being sent over IPv4. Could you try and replace it with `listen 80;` and restart the server?

Comment: @xyres Thank you so much.it is working now.I am fairly new to nginx & did not know that it will only take request from ipv6 only.I thought it will handle both.

Comment: I've added an answer with further details about the issue and how you can accept IPv6 traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listen [::]:80;`—this means nginx will only serve IPv6 requests. But seeing browser logs, the requests are being sent over IPv4.

To accept both IPv4 and IPv6, you can do this:

```
listen 80; # IPv4
listen [::]:80; # IPv6
```

Also, your domain `galentichrms.tk` only has an `A` DNS record (which is for IPv4). It doesn't have the `AAAA` record which maps an IPv6 address to a domain. That is why browser is sending request over IPv4.

If your hosting provider gave you an IPv6 address, you also need to configure the `AAAA` record to be able to accept IPv6 traffic.